# How to check for <object returned empty description check> in uitextfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I have a uitextfield and i have got a search option using this uitextfield.When i enter the text it works well but when i clear the text i get "object returned empty description check" when i print it using po command in  console. For checking this i have used the following code:

```
if(_nameTextField.text !=nil || _nameTextField.text.length !=0 || ![_nameTextField.text isEqual:@""]|| _nameTextField.text != NULL || ![_nameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]){

}
```

But still it enters into the loop

Comment: Use && (AND) instead of || (OR). If you use OR condition then it will check if any condition is true out of five. But if you use AND then it will check and  return true if and only if all the conditions are true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use && instead of ||

```
if(_nameTextField.text !=nil && _nameTextField.text.length !=0 && ![_nameTextField.text isEqual:@""]&& _nameTextField.text != NULL && ![_nameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, it will work

```
if(_nameTextField.text !=nil && _nameTextField.text.length > 0 ){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this..it help you:

```
    if (_nameTextField.text && _nameTextField.text.length!=0)
{


}
```